# Python 3 Class Inheritance: Police Officer --> Police Chief

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm trying to wrap my head around class inheritance. I'd like to have a `police_officer` class and a `police_chief` class. I want my chief to have special powers while also having the same powers as his officers. Here is what I have so far:

```
class police_officer(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def arrest(self, criminal):
        print(criminal + ' is under arrest!')
        jail.append(criminal)


class police_chief(police_officer):
    def fire_officer(self, officer):
        print(officer.name + ' was fired!')
        officers.remove(officer)


jail = []
officers = []

suspects = ['Joseph', 'Charles', 'Eric']

officers.append(police_officer('Edward'))
officers.append(police_officer('Jerry'))
officers.append(police_officer('Robert'))

chief = police_chief(officers[0])

officers[1].arrest(suspects[2])
chief.fire_officer(officers[2])
```

This seems to be working the way I'd like it to, but now I'd like to give my chief class a `def retire(self, new_chief)` function where he can retire and make one of the already existing officers the chief, not a whole new instance of `police_chief`. It would be even better if I could figure out a way for the chief to become a regular officer again while also choosing who the next chief should be. I hope I was clear enough in what I'm trying to do, I'm still pretty new to Python. Thanks!

Comment: You want an instance method on a `police_chief` (note: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) that takes a `police_officer` and converts it to another `police_chief`? Perhaps you should be using composition (i.e. the role is an attribute of a person)?

Comment: Are you meaning that I would be better off making `police_chief = True` a value under `police_officer`?

Comment: That would be one way to do it, yes.